# delete maintenance.file from cpanel

Tags: backup, maintenance

I tried to do a backup system using tools from the mangento cpanel online ( I don't have any local version on my computer).

the website is unreachable as well as the cpanel I have

> "Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable"

I have no clue how to delete the file to recover the controlpanel on the website

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can delete the maintenance file from the cpanel directly

Comment: You can contact you hosting provider for advance help

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete .flag file from cPanel in order to avoid 503 error.

[image: Delete Maintainance Flag]